# Convert text string in Tuesday, January 27, 2015 - 1:00 AM format to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a text string like "Tuesday, January 27, 2015 - 1:00 AM " and need help to convert this to a time stamp in excel.

I have tried to do text to columns and able to get the date piece, but having trouble with the time portion.

Has anyone any experience with an excel formula I could use.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Use the RIGHT function to strip off the last eight characters to get the time. That may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time value try

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,99))
```

Comment: Thank you Tetlyn that worked perfectly. WOuld you have any ideas on a similar formula I could use to convert both the date and time portion of the formula. I am having trouble converting using mid, left or right as the number of characters to fetch the month and date are different depending on the month or weekday.

Comment: The date portion is a bit trickier. There is the DATEVALUE() function which you can feed a text string, but what text is recognised depends on your regional settings, i.e. DMY vs. MDY. What shall it be?